# gdalinfo: /usr/pgsql-13/lib/libpq.so.5: no version information available (required by /lib64/libgdal.so.27)

Tags: postgis, gdal, postgresql, fedora

After the installation of postgis 3.1 and postgres 13, GDAL is complaining about libpq.so.5 library:

```
gdalinfo: /usr/pgsql-13/lib/libpq.so.5: no version information available (required by /lib64/libgdal.so.27)
```

I am running Fedora 33 and installed postgis and postgres from YUM, see [this guide](https://computingforgeeks.com/install-postgresql-13-on-fedora/). I am not using the default Fedora packages, because they offer older version. What is going on and how should I fix this?

Comment: Does the file `libpq.so.5` actually exist? What does `psql --version` tell? Also, this may help; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781566/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libpq-so-5-cannot-open-shared-object-file or this maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/30265074/6630397

Comment: By this ticket the error is probably on Fedora side https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/3596.